# UISplitViewController in Mac apps?

Tags: ipad, macos, uisplitviewcontroller

Is it possible to use UISplitViewController in a Mac app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's part of UIKit and thus not available on Mac. You can use `NSSplitView` if you need a view with multiple panes, but it has a very different API.

Besides, the most significant feature of `UISplitViewController` (handling auto-rotation and hiding the master view in portrait mode) doesn't make much sense in a Mac app, as the screen never rotates.

Answer (score 0):

If you're motivated to write your own, `MGSplitViewController` is a BSD-licensed general reimplementation of `UISplitViewController` for UIKit that *might* provide insight. Project available at [MGSplitViewController on Github](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController).